# Is it acceptable to create a dummy variable out of a quantitative variable?

Tags: logistic, regression-coefficients, categorical-encoding, continuous-data, predictor

I have a variable that takes the value of 5% or 10% throughout the data set. Is it okay to transform this variable into a dummy variable such that 10% (high) = 1 and 5% (low) = 0.
I am running a logistic regression (binary response variable) and I want to know if the probability of event success i.e. y=1 decreases when the variable X increases. Is it acceptable to code  10% (high) = 1 and 5% (low) = 0. I ran a regression with this variable as a quantitative variable, but the output (coefficient) seemed to be unordinary.

```
     Default | Coefficient  Std. err.      z    P>|z|     [95% conf. interval]


        x    |   15.46885   .2556751    60.50   0.000     14.96773    15.96996
```

Answer (score 4):

You can. But this transformation will just scale down your coefficient. The *z* and *p*-value should stay the same.

Comment: Thank you. If it is coded as a binary variable, how would the constant or intercept of logistic regression be interpreted? Would the constant indicate the probability of default(success event) when X=0? As such the probability y=1 when x=0, or in my case when x is low / 5%. Is this correct?

Comment: Is this interpretation of constant in logistic regression for my case correct? "The probability of default of loans(y=1. success event) when X is 5%/low is eβ0 ÷ (1 + eβ0)"

Comment: I think, yes, like this

Comment: Thank you! Do you have an explanation as to why the coefficient for X variable was extraordinarily large? For reference, my dataset contains over 300k observations, majority of the observations take the value of 10% and 5% otherwise. Is it because the variable does not follow a range, but rather strictly 2 values? My histogram for X variable is also weird, I have one bar each on right end and left end, representing 10% and 5% respectively. Rationally speaking, it is not an outlier rather a requirement for the  institution. continued in next comment

Comment: So, can you advise how I should deal with this variable? I have to run other regressions too with this variable where the dependent variable is continuous. I am usually advised against setting up dummy variables, so I wonder if transforming X variable to dummy is a good choice.

Comment: If 5% and 10% are the majority but not all observations, this transformation leads to losing information that is hidden in your dataset. The amplitude of the coefficient shouldn't scare you, because after the logit/probit transformation, it will become a probability (a very extreme one), that's all.

Comment: I am dealing with a loan data set of over 950k observations, where loans can be active, repaid or defaulted. In this dataset the variable X takes the value of 2%, 5% and 10%. But only 32 observations are 2%. For logistic regression, I am only dealing with loans that are either repaid or defaulted, as I am studying the probability of default, other researchers also follow the same approach and use only repaid or defaulted loans for this logistic regression. So in this dataset, the variable only takes the value of 5% or 10%. Also what do you mean by logit transformation? continued

Comment: I meant that even when you get a very large $\beta_1$ coefficient, it still needs to be transformed to become a probability, e.g., $\frac{1}{1-e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}}$. If $\beta_1 \to \infty$, the coefficient $\beta_0$ is constant, and $x=1$, then the probability $\frac{1}{1-e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x)}} \to 1$. In other words, the observations with $X=10\%$ were very very likely to repay their debt.

Comment: when y=1, it is default not repaid loans, so your interpretation here "the observations with X=10% were very very likely to repay their debt", you actually meant " X=10% were very very likely to *default* on their debt, right?

Comment: Then, yes, like that.